# a problem with tasters-combinatorial design theory

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

I have a collection of flavors being sampled in batches of $3$.  I know that each pair of flavors occur together in exactly one batch.  Also each flavor appears in the same number of batches.  How can i prove that there are a total of either $3$, $6n+1$ or $6n+3$ flavors?

So i know that this can be solved by using combinatorial design theory.
So i have knowledge about thsi kind of desings:

$(v,k,\lambda)$ and t-designs: $(v,k,\lambda_{t})$

and basically i have normally came across problems with 3 given data, and here i only have two:
$v=?$
$k=3$
$\lambda_{2}=1$
I am not completely sure, if it's a 2-design or a design.
I think that probably i should use some of the basic formula and also my knowledge of these subject is not really advanced, so i have only the recursion for $\lambda$ and two or three other formulas

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean "testers/tested/etc." or are are you describing a problem involving a group of people tasting stuff (i.e. with their mouths)?

Comment: tasting with mouth

Comment: Allright, could you then include some additional information with regard to the setup? For instance, different versions of what?

Comment: it's cheese.
different cheeses. It's really that important?

Comment: It's just so we have some context; it's always good to know the intention of the person asking, as it will be easier to follow their reasoning if you know what their goal with the reasoning is. So it's perhaps not essential for the math, but for the clarity of the question it's good. Alternatively (and perhaps better), you could - if you want to make it exclusively about the math - abstract your question so as to not include the specifics, such as "tasters".

Comment: understandable, so i think it's clear enough now i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that there are ${v \choose 2} = v(v-1)/2 = \frac{1}{2}(v^{2}-v)$ total pairs of flavors, and each must show up exactly once in a batch.  Since each batch has size $3$, each of the $b$ batches has ${3 \choose 2} = 3$ pairs showing up.  So $3b = \frac{1}{2}(v^{2}-v)$, or $6b = v^{2}-v$.

Now you have a quadratic equation, $v^{2}-v - 6b = 0$.  Find the solutions in terms of $b$ using the quadratic formula.  Keep in mind they have to be positive integers (since they are the number of flavors). Better yet, notice that this equation implies that $v^{2}-v \equiv 0 \bmod{6}$, and use this to show that $v \equiv 1$ or $3 \bmod{6}$. In this case you will need an extra argument to show that $v \not\equiv 0 \bmod{6}$.